# Symfony @Template(engine="php") not working on v2.6

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6

I had a site built using Symfony 2.1.x, now I migrated to Symfony 2.6 but it is always trying to find twig templates it doesn't matter that I had:

```
@Template(engine="php")
```

In each action.

The only way that I can do it work is adding:

```
return $this->render('PanelPaginaBundle:Default:index.html.php')
```

At the end of the action.

Is the template annotation no longer working in 2.6?
Is there anyother thing I have to do?

In config.yml I had:

```
templating: engines: ['twig', 'php']
```

Comment: The manual implies it should work: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php Are you sure you have the Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle properly installed and configured?

Comment: How I have to configured it?  I have it in the vendor folder, but I didn-t change anything

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html Pay attention to the S2.3 version change notes

Comment: In my AppKernel.php I have "new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),"  and in the autoloader.php located in app folder I have "AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));" but anyway the annotation is not working...